# IBM Websphere MQ FTE (File Transfer Edition) - Agent cannot be published

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I am quite new to MQ FTE and having issues to getting it work. Basically, I want to setup a simple environment between two queue managers that I can use to transfer files. Here is what i did:

1. One the first machine, I set up a queue manager and called it CMQ. Create a local queue called RECEIVED.MESSAGES and a remote queue SENT.MESSAGES. Also created a transmission queue.
2. Defined a transmission channels needed to communicate with the second queue manager.
3. One the second queue manager (SMQ), repeated the same process for creating local and remote queues, channels etc.

At this point, if I can both send and receive messages between the two Queue managers.

Next, on the first machine running queue manager CMQ, I carried out the following:

1. ran fteSetupCoordinate specifying the queue manager, host, port and channel SYSTEM.ADMIN.CONN
2. ran fteSetupCommand with the same details and specified host, port, channel (SYSTEM.ADMIN.CONN)
3. Ran the mqsc scipt file generated by fteSetupCoordinate.
4. Ran fteCreateAgent with QMgrName as CMQ, host, port and channel as SYSTEM.ADMIN.CONN

This is where the problem starts. The fteCreateAgent command end up with a message saying Agent was created successfully but could not registered with CMQ. The exact error is:

```
"BFGMQ1007I: The coordination queue manager cannot be contacted or has refused a connection attempt.

The WebSphere MQ reason code was 2058. The agent's presence will not be published.
```

I've tried every possible solution in forums and IBM's site including the troubleshooting found on this link:

But nothing works. As a result, the agent is never seen in MQ explorer. I also do not see the agent when I issue ftListAgent ..

Any ideas guys? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We're not all guys here.

Answer (score 0):

Get to know the `mqrc` command.  It is your friend.

```
mqrc 2058

      2058  0x0000080a  MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR
```

The error code you are getting back indicates that a connection was made to a QMgr but that it wasn't the one that was expected.  That means either you have a typo in the QMgr name when you ran `fteCreateAgent` or you pointed the agent to the wrong QMgr.